How to set up an cyclic event on anylogic
Hi I have a problem on anylogic, i'm working on a ship which cross a bridge based on tidal wave, every day the high tide only occur at 8 am and last for 10 hours, ship will cross only there is high tide occur. i am using hold block. i have set my event "hightide" with timeout-cyclic category which first occurance at 8 and reoccurance in 24 hours, but how to make that the event only last for 10 hour and then back to low tide. what is happening on my simulation the ship cross at 8 am but after that the ship is on hold untul the end of simulation. how i can make this happen and the event repeat every day (i use hour time unit)
thank you, i'm really new at java and anylogic, event set
only unblock at 8 am, and didnt go at 32, 64, etc
every help and step by step is instruction will be really helpful

Easiest: add another 2nd event that triggers the "off" setting. Make it trigger at 6pm every 24 hrs

thankyou benjamin it worked

pls upvote useful replies, helps future users with similar issues

Another good way to have it would be to have a specific schedule, instead of a pair of events.
The scheduled is specifically tailored for periodic schedules of on/off triggers, which is exactly the case here. This way, both logic (on and off) can be on the same TidalSchedule (and in the future it could be updated, if needed, with real-world tidal schedules as needed)


what a useful insight thankyou

Hi something else, how can i set MoveTo block speed based on this event ? is there any way to to this ?

You could use the MoveTo block to set agent speed. There is a checkmark Set Agent Speed. You would need a variable (agent_speed, for example). So the MoveTo block would set the agent speed to the variable agent_speed, and then the schedule/events can set the variable and change the speeds.

thankyou for your great answer & insight
